# Definition of function for integration

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have this function:

```
g33[p_] = Integrate[1/(a - b) (a μ2[-p/b] + μ1'[-p/b] - 
2 a g2'[(-a p)/b] - (a + b) g4'[-p]), {p, -l/b, 0}]
```

And I want to call it with other argument, but when I write this

```
g11[p_] = μ1[-p/a] - g2[-p] - g4[(-b p)/a] - g33[(b p)/a]
```

I get this reply

```
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {(b p)/a,-(l/b),0}. >>
```

How should I define `g33` properly?

Comment: the integration variable has to be a raw symbol. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what do you mean by raw symbol?
I'm trying to send `(b p)/a` as an argument to `g33`.

Comment: what @agentp means is that in your definition of g33, p is the variable along the path of integration. It cannot be a parameter as well. The integral in your definition of g33 is not a function of p.